# Guild not defined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I recently ran into a problem recently while trying to code a bot for my discord server. I'm getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: guild is not defined
```

Even though I have defined it in the bot's code (or at least it seems like it to me). What do I have to do to define it? Am I missing some important step here? I've looked at some other questions on this topic but none of the solutions seem to work.

Here's my bot's code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('*guild token*');

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return message.reply('this is not a valid command!');

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    if (command.permissions) {
        const authorPerms = message.channel.permissionsFor(message.author);
        if (!authorPerms || !authorPerms.has(command.permissions)) {
            return message.channel.reply('You can not do this!');
        }
    }

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }

    if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }

    const now = Date.now();
    const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 3) * 1000;

    if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
        const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

        if (now < expirationTime) {
            const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
            return message.reply(`please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`);
        }
    }

    timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
    setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);

    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you defined guild, but I cannot find where you are using it. Would be nice if you can show where exactly the error occurs.

And I noticed that you "censored", the guild ID at:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('*guild token*');
```

That is not necessary, because everyone could get the guild ID. And as I mentioned it is an ID not a token.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have included that. Here's my ban command that I got off of the discord.js site:
`module.exports = {
  name: 'ban',
  description: 'Bans a user.',
  guildOnly: true,
  args: true,
  usage: '<user>',
  cooldown: 5,
  permissions: 'BAN_MEMBERS',
  execute(message, args) {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    guild.members.ban(user);
  },
};`
The error also occurs in other commands with the guild constant, though.

Comment: yes you are using guild inside the command code of your ban command. But there your `guild` from your index is not visible. Or with other words, and how the error says: `guild` is not defined (not in your ban command code).